# select2 with ajax MVC does not hit results option

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I am using `select2` as `autocomplete` and select multiple options. Below is how I `initialize` `select2`

```
$(".selectpickerphone").select2({
  allowClear: true,
  minimumInputLength: 2,
  ajax: {
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetContactNumbers ", "HMController")",
    data: function(searchTerm) {
      return searchTerm;
    },
    results: function(data) {
      debugger;
      if (data.isUser) {
        return;
      }
      return {
        results: $.map([data], function(item) {
          return {
            text: item.name,
            id: item.PhoneNum,
            data: item
          }
        })
      };
    }
  },
  formatResult: function(response) {
    data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
    this.description =
      '<div id="fmu_select2_ajax_result">' +
      "<div>Nom du produit : " + data.name + "</div>" +
      "<div>" +
      "<div>" + data.PhoneNum+ "</div>" +
      "</div>" +
      '</div>';
    return this.description;
  },
  formatSelection: function(response) {
    data = response.data;
    return data.PhoneNum+ " - " + data.name;
  },
  escapeMarkup: function(m) {
    return m;
  },
  dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
});
```

Below is my `JsonResult` - `actionmethod`

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetContactNumbers(string term)
{
    using (_db = new Context())
    {
        _adRep = new ADRP();
        var contactList = _adRep.FetchCustomerUserPhone(_db,term);
        return Json(contactList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

and I get below response when viewed in network tab.

```
[{"name":"Guruprasad Rao","isUser":true,"PhoneNum":"8495000049"},
 {"name":"Guruprasad Rao","isUser":false,"PhoneNum":"8495000050"},
 {"name":"Test","isUser":false,"PhoneNum":"8495000051"}]
```

But no matter what, the debugger I've placed in `results` option of `ajax` does not get hit and thus data is also not displayed. How would I receive it as response and display it?

**Update**

I am using `select2 v4.0.1`

Comment: I would break this down into smaller functions so you can see which are being called correctly. You can always put it back together once you fix any problems...

Comment: @bukko As I said, the `results` callback never gets hit.. The `debugger` is in very first line..

Comment: I assume your controller action code is getting called ok?

Comment: Yes.. Its is.. @bukko.. That's how I get results..

Comment: `data` is an array of objects so `if (data.isUser) {` does not make sense

Comment: @StephenMuecke Agreed and made a note of it.. But the problem was different.. I've solved it.. thanks for your time..  :)

Comment: @bukko Thanks for your time.. The problem has been solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution**

I had to use `processResults` instead of `results` in `$.ajax`. Got to know when I actually visited the **[official site](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)**. May be it has been changed for `version > 4.0`.

```
processResults: function(data) {
  return {
    results: $.map(data, function(item) {
      return {
        text: item.name,
        id: item.PhoneNum,
        data: item
      }
    })
  };
}
```

Along with that `formatResult` and `formatSelection` have been changed to `templateResult` and `templateSelection` after the said version. 

### [`Docs here`](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#templating)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it to bind in asp.net mvc 5.

i used **web services ,Controller Http post method, Web Api 2** but that does not use in call back event of select2 .

Use `Asp.net Generic handler` to produce callback result then try to bind it to select2.